# Use capture in pattern?

Tags: .net, regex

With this pattern I can match this text

Patern:

```
"abc\(.*?\)abc"
```

Text:

```
"abc(" "")abc"
```

What if I want the user to decide how to start and end it. Instead of abc it could be anything

Pattern:

```
"(.*?)\(.*?\)$1"
```

Text:

```
"def(" "")def"
```

Except this doesn't work because it appears $ means end of line and not match with group 1. Is it possible to match the way I want with regex in .NET?

Comment: Try to use `\1` instead of `$1`. [demo](http://regex101.com/r/rE1qQ4)

Comment: `$1` is for the replacement string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've mostly seen `$1` used in the replace section. But in the expression it won't work, you have to use `\1`, so your expression would look like: `"(.*?)\(.*?\)$1"`.

Let's improve it a bit. We could match explicitely using a negative character class: `\([^)]+\)`. `[^)]+` means match anything except closing bracket one or more times. That way we've also eliminated empty brackets.

Now let's apply what we've just learned and make the expression also accept single quotes: `("|')(.*?)\([^)]+\)\2\1`

```
("|')   # match either a single or double quote and put it in group 1
(.*?)   # match anything ungreedy zero or more times until ... and put it in group 2
\(      # match opening parenthesis (
[^)]+   # match anything except closing parenthesis ) one or more times
\)      # match closing parenthesis
\2      # match what was matched in group 2
\1      # match what was matched in group 1
```

---

For future reference, we could also use named groups. You can declare a named group in .NET with the following syntax `(?<namedgroup>.*?)`. You may then use a backreference like the following `\k<namedgroup>` in the expression. **Remember this syntax is for .NET only**. PCRE has another syntax.

Taking our expression above as an example would result into the following pattern:
`(?<quotes>"|')(?<str>.*?)\([^)]+\)\k<str>\k<quotes>`

<kbd>[**Online .NET regex demo**](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28?%3Cquotes%3E%22%7C%27%29%28?%3Cstr%3E.%2a?%29%5C%28%5B%5E%29%5D%2b%5C%29%5Ck%3Cstr%3E%5Ck%3Cquotes%3E&i=%22def%28%22%20%22%22%29def%22%0D%0A%27def%28%22%20%22%22%29def%27)</kbd>
                                                                                       
<kbd>[**For further reading >>>**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html)</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `\1` inside the regex pattern to backreference a capture group:

```
"(.*?)\(.*?\)\1"
```

Comment: I don't suppose its possible to use a name? I tried \name but that didn't work out. I moved that pattern to the front and it works as expected. (Its a large pattern)